# convert a numpy 3d array to a 1d of 2d arrays

Tags: python, numpy

How can I convert a 3D numpy array into sub-dimension arrays? 
For example, I have a 3D numpy array of shape(100,3,3) and I want to convert it into a vector of 100 2D arrays of shape (3,3)?

Comment: Trying to get the bigger picture - Why do you need that?

Comment: just in case what you're trying to do is import cells into matlab / octave: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960464/using-scipy-io-savemat-to-save-nested-lists/38961751#38961751

Comment: As @Divakar mentioned, why would you need that? A 3d array it is by definition a 1d of 2d :S You can do same slicing operations to a 3d numpy array than to a list of 2d arrays.

Comment: the point is i want to join several arrays(diffent dimensions)in one 2d array, i tried with column_stack() but didnt' work.

Answer (score 6):

For doing this, use the `numpy.split` function. Assuming you have

```
my_array = np.zeros((100, 3, 3))
```

use:

```
my_new_array = np.split(my_array, 100, axis=0).
```

From this you will get an array containing 100 arrays with shape (1,3,3). If you like to get a list with the (3,3) arrays, just use a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [my_array[i] for i in range(np.shape(my_array)[0])]
```

.

Comment: or just `my_list = list(my_array)`

Comment: I like this one. This is even more simple.

Comment: This produces a list of arrays, not an array of arrays.

Comment: my_array already is an array of arrays. You can slice it directly by `my_array[4]` for example

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960464/using-scipy-io-savemat-to-save-nested-lists/38961751#38961751) which needed this in order for the individual 3x3 arrays to become cell elements in savemat:

```
import numpy
A = numpy.zeros((100,3,3))
B = numpy.empty((100,), dtype=numpy.object)
for i in range(100): B[i] = A[i,:,:]
```